# I don't understand why it is giving this output?

Tags: c, switch-statement

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main ()
{
    int i=0;
    for (i=0; i<21; i++)
    {
        switch(i)
        {
            case 0:
            i+=5;
            case 1:
            i+=2;
            case 5:
            i+=5;
            default:
            i+=4;

            break;
        }
        printf("%d   ",i);
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Now the Output of this program is 16 21 I don't understand why this program is giving this output when the limit of the loop is less than 18 it gives only 16 but when value is greater than 18 output is 16 21 any help

Comment: Please change the title of your post to something more meaningful. Also, please use indentation.

Comment: You realize your switch statements are all falling through? The code does what it says it does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put `break` statements at the end of each case.  Otherwise each case will 'fall through' to the next one.